# input type=image and ie8

Tags: html, internet-explorer-8

I have an image button that works fine with fire fox but does not work with ie8. Please help me.

```
<input type="image"  tabindex="8" name="submit_submit" value="submit" src="images/continues.jpg" />
```

I have a php file that has a form. Forms action button calls to file itself. When submit button is pressed in ie8, following code is not executed.

```
if(isset($_POST["submit"]))
{
      code
    }
```

while if button is pressed in other browsers function above executes.

Comment: it submits form in ff but does not submit in ie8.

Comment: please post the full code, there's nothing wrong with that snippet.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Some browsers do not support values on image inputs.

Check for the presence of coordinates.

```
if(isset($_POST["submit_submit"]) || isset($_POST["submit_submit_x"]))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if(isset($_POST["submit_submit"]))
{
    //code
}
```

This should work

Answer (score 1):

You named it `submit_submit`. Sooo, it gets sent as `submit_submit`, not `submit`.

```
if(isset($_POST["submit_submit"])) { }
```

Also, do a `var_dump($_POST['submit_submit'])` to ensure it's the right thing. The `value="` might not work in IE8 in which case just test if its set at all.

Alternatively, just use `type="submit"` with a background image and text-offset technique.